# Assign Linux File System Type to Variable

Tags: linux, bash, file, filesystems

I am attempting to assign the Linux File System Type to a variable.
My output of commant `df -Th | grep "^/dev"`
is as follows:

```
/dev/mapper/rhel-root xfs        50G   11G   40G  22% /
/dev/mapper/rhel-home xfs        53G  569M   53G   2% /home
/dev/sdb1             xfs      1014M  192M  823M  19% /boot
/dev/sdc1             vfat      7.6G  7.4G  125M  99% /run/media/root/RHEL-8-1-0-
```

My solution was to pipe this to an awk statement to return the type for rhel-root, however I do not get any output.

```
var=$(awk '{
  if($1 == "/dev/mapper/rhel-root"){
    print $2;
    }
  }' | df -Th | grep "^/dev")
```

How do I assign the file type (xfs) to a variable?

Comment: Use `var=$(df ... | grep ... | awk ...)` and I suggest to add option -P to your `df` command.

Comment: What @Cyrus means is that you need to generate the data with `df` and `grep` before you feed the output to `awk`, so `awk` needs to be last in the pipeline, not first.  It's curious that you get no output — you should get all the text shown as the output of `df … | grep …` in the variable.  `df` does not read standard input.  I suppose bash might get hung up waiting for `awk` to terminate — it _is_ attempting to read standard input.  Did you have to interrupt the code?  I did!

Answer (score 1):

You need to feed the output of the pipeline `df .. grep ..` to the `awk`
command as an input:

```
var=$(awk '{
  if($1 == "/dev/mapper/rhel-root"){
    print $2;
    }
  }' <(df -Th | grep "^/dev") )
echo "$var"
```

Then it will output: `xfs`.

A generalized solution will be:

```
declare -A array                # assiciative array
while read -r fs type others; do
    if [[ $fs = /dev/* ]]; then
        array[$fs]="$type"      # associate fs with its type
    fi
done < <(df -Th)

echo "${array[/dev/mapper/rhel-root]}"
```